# Flutter-pub get showing error: ) was unexpected at this time

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-packages, pubspec

Every time I try running pub get or pub upgrade the following error is returned:[Working dir: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\flutterr_app
"C:\Program Files\Dart\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat" get
) was unexpected at this time.
Process finished with exit code 255][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv09t.jpg even if i try opening another project the error persists. The actual code is showing errors such as the ones below: [error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter/material.dart'. (uri_does_not_exist at [flutterr_app] lib\main.dart:1)][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pPRb.jpg I have tried changing the dart and android studio versions and even re-installing flutter but the problem is still there.
Code in pubspec.yaml
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1e6z.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDDoT.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKShA.jpg

Comment: can I see the code inside your pubspec.yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with your Dart SDK path.
Open Android Studio, Go to File->Settings. Scroll down to bottom and select
Language & Frameworks. Click on dart and share your Dart SDK path.

Answer (score 0):

In your project open terminal and write `flutter pub get`. it should remove all the errors. If not, share your **pubspec.yaml** code.

It's very common to have this error. Running flutter pub gets all the dependencies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I once tried, it still returns the same error.